# dojo.exists fails with IE11

Tags: javascript, dojo, xpages, internet-explorer-11, lotus-domino

Since a few days, I have troubles with `Internet Explorer 11` in conjunction with `dojo toolkit 1.9.4` hosted by a `Domino Server`.

*Source Code:*

---

```
if (dojo.exists("btnUpload")) {
    console.log("btnUpload exist ... do something...");
} else {
    console.log("btnUpload doesn't exist...");
}
```

With IE11 the return value of `dojo.exists()` is always **false**!

*IE11 Debugger:*

---

[image]

However in all other browser (Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, Apple Safari) it works!

Comment: [Works fine](http://jsbin.com/vineqo/edit), using a fully-patched IE11.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using dojo version 1.9.4 maybe that's the reason...

Comment: Nope: http://jsbin.com/vineqo It's much more likely to be an error in your code than IE or Dojo. Remember: [`select` isn't broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips). Most likely some subtle timing problem.

Comment: Maybe related...in XPages the isIE() method returns false for IE 11, but works for older versions.  http://xcellerant.net/2014/01/08/detecting-ie11-in-xpages/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thanks for your example (http://output.jsbin.com/vineqo) it also works perfect for me :) I am using a `IBM Domino Server` which is providing the dojo version 1.9.4 and I think I have to do some investigations in this direction.

Comment: **First findings:** This dojo code https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.4/dojo/dojo.js looks different from the code http://myWebServer/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.9.4/dojo/dojo.js provided by my Domino Web Server. It looks like IBM have done some customization...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `dojo.exists` for this isn't very appropriate, given that `btnUpload` is technically just a DOM ID, and not an actual object in the global scope.  `if (document.getElementById('btnUpload'))` would seem to be far more appropriate in this case.

When a global reference is encountered that doesn't match an actual global variable, but does match a DOM ID, browsers tend to return the DOM node, but I wouldn't recommend relying upon that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have rewritten my code. Now I am using `dojo.byId("btnUpload")` instead of `dojo.exists("btnUpload")` an all works perfect. I am using `dojo.byId` instead of `document.getElementById` for browser independence.